# Reading Mikolov's trained word vectors using Python

Tags: python, c++, word2vec

I am trying to read the binary file at [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/edit?usp=sharing). This file contains word representations has been trained by Mikolov in [word2vec](https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/) program and seem to have format as follow:

12 first bytes contain string: "3000000 300\n"

Subsequent bytes: "<1st variable word string>[space]<4*300 bytes to form 300 dimension float vector>**[May be something there]**<2nd word>....<3000000th word>[space]<4*300 bytes>"

With this `C` code:

```
fscanf(in_file, "%s%c", &buff, &ch);
for (a = 0; a < size; a++) fread(&M[a], sizeof(float), 1, in_file);
```

I can read each word store in `buff` and corresponding vector store in `M`. But when i try the same strategy in `Python` with this test code:

```
_f = open("GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin")
print _f.read(12)
print _f.read(4), _f.read(1) == ' '
_f.read(4*300)
print _f.read(2), _f.read(1) == ' '
_f.read(4*300)
print _f.read(3), _f.read(1) == ' '
_f.read(4*300)
print _f.read(1), _f.read(1) == ' '
```

It produces the result:

3000000 300

`</s>` True

in True

for True

; False

Obviously wrong because the third word must be `that`. I cant figure out what i am doing wrong here!

Comment: My guess is that you are on windows where opening the file as text file instead of binary there is actually a difference. Always open binary files in binary mode. I can't reproduce the problem on Linux.

Comment: Thanks @BlackJack, that is exactly the problem :-)